# How to pass a javascript variable on a jsp to a servlet

Tags: javascript, ajax, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am using google visualization API java wrapper to create a reporting module. I am using image charts.

Now I want to pass the url of the generated chart to a servelet. I can get the url of the generated graph using `getImageUrl()` method. I have stored the value of that url in a javascript variable.

How can I pass the URL through ajax?

Answer (score 2):

Pass it as one of the parameters in $.ajax(); or $.post(); if you are using jquery. just as you would pass any other data in an Ajax call. An example would be:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: urlToCall,
  data: { 'param': valueOfParam },

});
```

Pass it as param is passed above.

Comment: can't we do it using javascript? without using jquery?

Comment: Sure u can. Here's an example: http://blogs.digitss.com/javascript/simple-plain-ajax-without-any-javascript-library/